# PHP Not Passing Correct JSON Result

Tags: php, json

Hello All I have made a php for my android application project which creates a json containing the returned data from database 
but the problem is that it is not returning anything except "[]" square brackets.

FetchUserData.php

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("mysql8.000webhost.com" , "====" , "passwordGoesHere" , "=====");

$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss" , $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement ,$userID , $name , $age , $username , $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user[name] = $name;
    $user[age] = $age;
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[password] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What do you get if you run the query directly in your database?

Comment: You need to var_dump($user) to see what you're actually getting, because based on this code, it shouldn't be empty unless the array is empty.

Comment: just a thought but try commenting out "mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);"

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using what the php parser interprets as undefined constants. You're not wrapping your keys in quotations. Should be:

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user['name'] = $name;
    $user['age'] = $age;
    $user['username'] = $username;
    $user['password'] = $password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your sql query whether it is returning any result or not. I think your query is not giving any result. Hence you are getting blank array. Run your query directly into database & check whether  you are getting anything